# Text Box Seems To Not Be Centred But Hugging Side of Document

Tags: microsoft-word

A family member is currently writing a book but when they loaded up the document to make some changes, all the text seems to be hugging the left hand side.

Anyone know what would cause this?

[image]

Comment: Is every page using a text box? It also almost looks like it could be a tabs (and that little `L` thing I can't remember the name of) issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Margin and Indent handles have been dragged to the left somehow.

This image is from Google Docs, but the results should be the same under Office 2010:

[image: Example]

As you can see, in the top left corner there is a little blue Rectangle and Triangle. These are probably grey in Office 2010:

[image: Margin and Indent]

You'll need to drag these back to where they should be. To do this, you have to activate the Ruler. On the very right hand side, just above the scroll bar there should be a little button:

[image: Ruler Button]

Click this to bring the ruler back, then grab the margin and indent handles and drag them back to where you want them to be.

[image: Done!]